# Authjs - Error API call been made to "/auth/auth/" instead of "/auth"

Tags: next.js, next-auth

**Environment**

```
System:

OS: macOS 13.5

CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz

Memory: 1.93 GB / 32.00 GB

Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh

Binaries:

Node: 20.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node
npm: 10.2.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/npm

Browsers:

Brave Browser: 111.1.49.132

Chrome: 122.0.6261.112

Safari: 16.6

npmPackages:
@auth/prisma-adapter: ^1.0.11 => 1.5.0
next: 14.0.4 => 14.0.4
next-auth: ^5.0.0-beta.15 => 5.0.0-beta.15
react: ^18 => 18.2.0
```

**Reproduction URL**
https://github.com/RicSala/next-boilerplate.git

**Issue**
When the user provides invalid credentials, an api call is made to:

http://localhost:3000/api/auth/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin&code=credentials

instead of:

http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin&code=credentials

(Note the double auth path)

resulting in a bad request, a UnknownAction error and the signin flow ending prematurely.

**How to reproduce**
Clone de repo
Run npm install && npm run dev
Got to the signin page at: /auth/signin
Try to signup with made up credentials
You will be redirected to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin&code=credentials as a result of the invalid api call

**Expected behavior**
The api call should be made to
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin&code=credentials

thus returning the user to the signin page with the error query param to give feedback to the user

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! This would've been a tricky one if you wouldn't have known what you are searching for. Inside your `middleware.ts` file you have the following statement:

```js
if (isPrivate && !isLoggedIn) {
  return Response.redirect(new URL('/auth/signin', nextUrl)); // <- your problem
}
```

You are adding the `/auth/signin` segment to whatever the **current** url is rather than using it as the final location. To fix this you can use the `origin` property. Here is an example that incorporates a fix:

```js
if (isPrivate && !isLoggedIn) {
  return Response.redirect(new URL('/auth/signin', nextUrl.origin));
}
```

Comment: Big thank you Fabio! Will test it tomorrow morning and update the answer!

Comment: Fabio, I tried completely remove the middleware (and run rm -rf .next and node_modules) but still the issue persists.

Any other idea? Thank you!

Comment: @Ric Likely your browser still has cached the redirect. Try it with another browser or clear your browser cache.